# Visa got rejected by Agentur for Arbeit

Tags: visa, germany, immigration, blue-card, refusal

I'm Abhishek, a recent master's graduate in Germany. I got a job as a financial data analyst from a third-party company and the contract is for 6 months. However, my residence permit was rejected by the Agentur für Arbeit in accordance with Section 40, Paragraph 1, No. 2 of the Residence Act. I'm looking for help as my visa expires on February 2nd and I don't know what to do?

[Residence Act](https://germanlawarchive.iuscomp.org/?p=1464)

> Section 40 Grounds for denial
>
> (1) Approval pursuant to Section 39 must be denied if [...]
>
> 2. the foreigner intends to take up employment as a temporary worker (Section 1 (1) of the Act on Temporary Employment Businesses).

Comment: Are you a citizen of the European Union? Are you sure you applied for a residency permit and not a tourist visa? If you applied for a permit, what kind of permit? There are 3 different types of residency permits. It is essential that non-EU expats have their permit in order before they arrive. On what kind of visa did you arrive?

Answer (score 1):

In case this is not clear, a **temporary worker** [Leiharbeitnehmer, Zeitarbeit]

- where the Employer loans out the employee to other employers

will **not** be issued a residence permit that allows you to work.

This is why the application for the residence permit was refused.

A 3rd country national, that allready has a residence permit **and** does not require a further approval from the *Agentur für Arbeit* can be employed in such a manor.

To resolve this, you should find a job where you actually work for the employer and offers a contract that is not time restricted.

---

**Sources**:

- [§40 - Act on the Residence, Economic Activity and Integration of Foreigners in the Federal Territory1) Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0901)

  - [§1 - Act on Temporary Agency Work (Arbeitnehmerüberlassungsgesetz – AÜG)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_a_g/englisch_a_g.html#p0013)